# Awesome WM does not recognise any touchpad clicks

Tags: mouse, archlinux, awesome-wm, touchpad

I am using arch and installed awesome wm manager.
Everything works fine, but the touchpad cklick doesnt work.
I also installed a gnome desktop and there the touchpad click works fine.
The movement on awesome works, and also xev recognises the movement. But not the clicks

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is, that I had to enable the driver.